# Perform a task if post is shared successfully by the user using facebook SDK share button

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have used facebook SDK share button in my website. Is it possible to show a success message or perform a task if a web page is shared successfully by the user?

Comment: No, that is not possible any more. It has been removed, because it was abused too much by spammers who “rewarded” users for sharing, which is against platform policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See example on this [docs page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.ui):

```
FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'share',
    href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
  },
  // callback
  function(response) {
    if (response && !response.error_message) {
      alert('Posting completed.');
    } else {
      alert('Error while posting.');
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: i have used this but still not getting any alert message after successful sharing.